# trouble getting incron inotify to work

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, incron

so after alex answer here are my steps :

creating shell code

```
root@ip[/]# touch mylog.sh
root@ip[/]# nano mylog.sh
```

copying the code in the mylog.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File $1 created." >> /mylog.log
```

permission

```
root@ip[/]# chmod +x mylog.sh
```

creating the log file

```
root@ip[/]# touch mylog.log
```

opening icron table

```
incrontab -e
```

putting new command in

```
/test/ IN_CREATE mylog.sh $@$#
```

reloading incron - creating a new file - checking the  log file

```
root@ip[/]# incrontab --reload
requesting table reload for user 'root'...
request done

root@ip[/]# cd test
root@ip[/test]# touch newfile.txt

root@ip[/test]# cd /
root@ip[/]# nano mylog.log
```

but still empty log file ... am i missing something ?

---

finally calling shell script with full path did the trick 
so  :

```
/test/ IN_CREATE /mylog.sh $@$#
```

Comment: Might want to ask this on serverfault or unix.stackexchange instead

Comment: Since in this case you have to write a shell script to make it work, the question is ok. See my answer below.

Comment: What does /var/log/messages say after you creat a file in /test?

Comment: Also be sure that your shell script is found. If you're not sure, then call the script with its full path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually find the incron logs in **/var/log/messages**

If you want to log events to a specific file you can use:

```
/test/ IN_CREATE mylog.sh $@$#
```

where mylog.sh is a shell script which handles the logging.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File $1 created." >> /home/myuser/filescreated.log
```

Don't forget to give execution permission to this shell script by chmod +x mylog.sh

Explanation:
As soon as you start using parameters for your command which you're calling, you have to put it all into a shell script. Since incron don't pass the arguments to your command but interprets it as an argument for itself.

Don't forget to call incrontab --reload after changing the incrontab.

### Another example

incrontab -e

```
/text/ IN_CREATE /home/myuser/mylog.sh $@ $#
```

mylog.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date) File $2 in $1 created." >> /home/myuser/log.txt
```

Comment: just a quick followup , is that possible to send file path and action to shell script ... i want my to watch multiple directory and multiple action ... so iwant my   shell script to be something like `echo "File $1 in the $2 directory was $3 ." `  like `File a.txt in the /path/to/file/ was deleted `

Comment: See my new example. Since incron calls a shellscript, you can do anything you want.

Comment: On a different note, the `incron` logs are found alongside `cron` logs for the specific distribution (i.e. `/var/log/cron`, `/var/log/syslog`).

Answer (score 0):

Following with Alexander's Baltasar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35175006/4352306), you could also have a script that does the redirection, and keep your end scripts free of that logic.

Below `std_wrapper.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

### FLAGS
set -Eeuo pipefail

### INIT SCRIPT
SCRIPT_FULLNAME=$(basename -- ${0})
usage="usage: ${SCRIPT_FULLNAME} log_file target_script target_file watched_dir event"


## ARGUMENTS
log_file="${1}"
target_script="${2}"
target_file="${3}"
watched_dir="${4}"
event="${5}"

### MAIN
if [ -z "${log_file}" ] || [ -z "${target_script}" ] || [ -z "${target_file}" ]; then
  echo "${usage}" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# do the actual call and apply the redirection:
${target_script} "${target_file}" "${watched_dir}" "${event}" >> "${log_file}" 2>&1
```

- make sure the script can be run (`$ chmod 770 std_wrapper.sh`):

In your `incrontab` (`$ incrontab -e`):

```
/test/ IN_CREATE /path/std_wrapper.sh /path/log/test.create /path/actual_script.sh $# $@ $%
```

`actual_script.sh` could look something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

### FLAGS
set -Eeuo pipefail

### Input Parameters
filename="${1}"
watched_dir="${2}"
event="${3}"
full_filename="${watched_dir}${filename}"

### Main
dt="$(date '+%d/%m/%YT%H:%M:%S')"
echo "$dt (event:) $event (file:) $filename (dir:) $watched_dir <----- going to process ----->"
echo "sleeping 10 seconds..."
sleep 10
dt="$(date '+%d/%m/%YT%H:%M:%S')"
echo "$dt (event:) $event (full_filename:) $full_filename <----- returning from sleep -->"
```

Creating two files consecutively (in less than 10 seconds)

```
$ touch /test/new-file && sleep 5 && touch /test/another-file
```

Would create a log like this:

```
$ cat /path/log/test.create
07/11/2022T08:00:50 (event:) IN_CREATE (file:) new-file (dir:) /test/ <----- going to process ----->
sleeping 10 seconds...
07/11/2022T08:00:55 (event:) IN_CREATE (file:) another-file (dir:) /test/ <----- going to process ----->
sleeping 10 seconds...
07/11/2022T08:01:10 (event:) IN_CREATE (full_filename:) /test/new-file <----- returning from sleep -->
07/11/2022T08:01:15 (event:) IN_CREATE (full_filename:) /test/another-file <----- returning from sleep -->
```